# An Exercise from Theory of Plane Curves

Tags: calculus

It was an exercise given in the class:

> For every integer $n\geq 0$, there is a function (curve) $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f$ is $n$-times differentiable with $n$-th derivative continuous, and $f(\mathbb{R})$ is the V-shaped graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
>   $$f(\mathbb{R})=\{ x,|x|\}.$$

I initially was saying, *this is wrong*, but Teacher's said, *Think over it; its elementary but interesting problem.*

I tried this, but couldn't solve. It may be very elementary, but I was comparing with function $x\mapsto |x|$, and hence may getting confused.

Any **Hint** for it?

Comment: so stupid! I was thinking, "by taking $f(x)=(x^n, |x|^n)$, it will not be a straight line; but thats not the case. Now its clear.

Comment: Sorry! This will work only when $n$ is odd. What about $n$ even?

Answer (score 1):

The map $f(x) = (x^3, |x|^3)$ will work for $n=2$.

Comment: sorry! This will work when $n$ is odd. If $n$ is even, then $f(t)=(t^n, |t|^n)$ will not work, since the image is only in first quadrant. How to proceed for $n$ even?